# Extract data elements found in a single column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Here is what my data look like.

```
id interest_string
1       YI{Z0{ZI{
2             ZO{
3            <NA>
4             ZT{
```

As you can see, can be multiple codes concatenated into a single column, seperated by {.  It is also possible for a row to have no `interest_string` values at all.

How can I manipulate this data frame to extract the values into a format like this:

```
id  interest
1    YI
1    Z0
1    ZI
2    Z0
3    <NA>
4    ZT
```

I need to complete this task with `R`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Damn, Gavin beat me, I got this far `do.call(c, apply(df, 1, function(x) strsplit(x[[2]],"\\{")[[1]]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one solution

```
out <- with(dat, strsplit(as.character(interest_string), "\\{"))
## or
# out <- with(dat, strsplit(as.character(interest_string), "{", fixed = TRUE))

out <- cbind.data.frame(id = rep(dat$id, times = sapply(out, length)),
                        interest = unlist(out, use.names = FALSE))
```

Giving:

```
R> out
  id interest
1  1       YI
2  1       Z0
3  1       ZI
4  2       ZO
5  3     <NA>
6  4       ZT
```

#### Explanation

The first line of solution simply splits each element of the `interest_string` factor in data object `dat`, using `\\{` as the split indicator. This indicator has to be escaped and in R that requires two `\`. *(Actually it doesn't if you use `fixed = TRUE` in the call to `strsplit`.)* The resulting object is a list, which looks like this for the example data

```
R> out
[[1]]
[1] "YI" "Z0" "ZI"

[[2]]
[1] "ZO"

[[3]]
[1] "<NA>"

[[4]]
[1] "ZT"
```

We have almost everything we need in this list to form the output you require. The only thing we need external to this list is the `id` values that refer to each element of `out`, which we grab from the original data.

Hence, in the second line, we bind, column-wise (specifying the data frame method so we get a data frame returned) the original `id` values, each one repeated the required number of times, to the `strsplit` list (`out`). By unlisting this list, we unwrap it to a vector which is of the required length as given by your expected output. We get the number of times we need to replicate each `id` value from the lengths of the components of the list returned by `strsplit`.

Answer (score 5):

A nice and tidy `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table( read.table( textConnection("id interest_string
1       YI{Z0{ZI{
2             ZO{
3            <NA>
4             ZT{"), header=TRUE))

DT$interest_string <- as.character(DT$interest_string)

DT[, {
  list(interest=unlist(strsplit( interest_string, "{", fixed=TRUE )))
}, by=id]
```

gives me

```
   id interest
1:  1       YI
2:  1       Z0
3:  1       ZI
4:  2       ZO
5:  3     <NA>
6:  4       ZT
```

Comment: That's very nice; as someone who doesn't use **data.table** much it is always enlightening to see how those who do put it to good use. **+1**. I suspect, this solution will have the edge (probably decidedly so) if the problem were very large, given the efficient ways **data.table** manipulates/creates data frames.